# Knex/Node/MySQL from YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS to just YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I would like to remove the time aspect from the date when retrieving it from the database, this is the code that I have for it but it isn't functional, could someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
.whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT( ap_meeting.horodate, "%Y-%m-%d" )' = conditions.dateMax)
```

Some context:

```
    var dateTime = new Date();
    dateMin = moment(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    dateMax = moment(dateMin).add(48, 'hours').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Comment: Is `conditions.datemax` a local variable or a table field?

Comment: Local, it takes todays date then add 48 hours :

Comment: var dateTime = new Date();

dateMin = moment(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

dateMax = moment(dateMin).add(2, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");

Comment: then your code should probably look like `.whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT( ap_meeting.horodate, "%Y-%m-%d" ) = \'' + conditions.dateMax + '\'')`

Comment: I think that did it! Much appreciated Nick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to make the answer nice and clear for all, thank you Nick for the speedy and on point reply!

```
.whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT( ap_meeting.horodate, "%Y-%m-%d" ) = \'' + conditions.dateMax + '\'')
```